# Extend styles to mimic bootstrap classes?

Tags: css, django, bootstrap-4, jinja2, extend

I have some patterns that appear which, when that happens, I would like to apply the styles of a bootstrap class to my selected element. The reason is that I don't directly have access to the elements in question as they are pre-generated  and fed into my jinja template.

Example:
Everytime I have a button in a form that I want my custom css to extend to mimic btn and btn-outline-primary classes and apply their styles to my selected button. Say then I modify the styles I extended so this button also has small caps.

I've tried this, to no avail:

```
form button{
    @extend .btn
    @extend .btn-outline-primary
    font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

How do I correctly reference this outside style sheet and extend its classes? Any solution for this that works out the box without add-ons is preferred.

Comment: @extend is sass, not css. If you are using a sass compiler, you could include a copy of the external css in your projects as an .scss file. Another option is to use javascript to add the classes to the appropriate elements.

Comment: ill add django and jinja in here since those are the techs im using, is sass compiling built in?

Comment: No, but people include it in their build utility (grunt, gulp, compass) - maybe this link can help. https://github.com/jrief/django-sass-processor